# Kickstarter and Amazon Payments: "functionality has been disabled"

Tags: amazon, kickstarter

So, [Double Fine's Kickstarter effort](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/66710809/double-fine-adventure) is about to come to a spectacular end.

While they clearly do not need my help, I have been trying to fund the project. Kickstarter uses Amazon Payments to process transactions, and the final step of checkout shoots you over to their site:

[image: screen shot]

However, having logged into my amazon.com account, I get redirected to a page reading: "This functionality has been disabled for your account. Please contact-us to know more."

If I try to create a new amazon.com user at https://payments.amazon.com, the 'Country' field is locked to 'United States' and can't be edited. It may be relevant that my Amazon account has my country as Australian, seeing as that's where I live.

Why will they not take my money?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, no thanks to the canned response I got from Amazon.

I had to create a new Amazon.com account (rather than a new Amazon Payments account, as the canned response told me to), then use that to sign into Amazon Payments.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it isn't Kickstarter's fault but rather Amazon Payments requirements that a bank based in the US is used to fund accounts. Reading through their [User Agreement](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/helpTab/Personal-Accounts/User-Agreement-Policies/User-Agreement) I found no reference to the ability to create an account outside of the United States.